# Unable to get time form the NTP server in esp8266, arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, ntp, platformio

I know I am successfully connected to the network as it's visible in my phone's hotspot. However I am unable to get the time using <Time.h> library through NTP server.

Thanks in advance. I will really appreciate your suggestions.

`platformio.int`

```
board_build.f_cpu = 160000000L
platform = espressif8266
board = nodemcuv2
framework = arduino
lib_deps = 
    paulstoffregen/Time@^1.6
```

`Arduino code`

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Time.h>
#include "WifiCtrl.h"   // Wifi setup
WifiCtrl WifiControl;


void setup()
{
    // Starting serial monitor service
    // ----------------------------------------------
    Serial.begin(9600);

    // This address the function which is for wifi setup
    WifiControl.setWifi();


    // Load time from the NTP server...
    time_t now;
    // Serial.println("Setting time using SNTP");
    configTime(5 * 3600, 1800, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");
    now = time(nullptr);

    struct tm timeinfo;
    gmtime_r(&now, &timeinfo);
    Serial.print("Current time: ");
    Serial.print(asctime(&timeinfo));
}

void loop() {}
```

Comment: I believe you are implementing "gmtime_r" function in wrong way. Have you gone through the docs properly.

Comment: Any way you must wait some time before printing the time, as it takes some time to get the time data from pool.ntp.org servers.

Comment: it should be `#include <time.h>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must wait sometime before printing the time data.

Hope this work for you

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Time.h>

void setup()
{
    // Starting serial monitor service
    // ----------------------------------------------
    Serial.begin(9600);

    // Load time from the NTP server...
    time_t now;
    // Serial.println("Setting time using SNTP");
    configTime(5 * 3600, 1800, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");
    now = time(nullptr);

    // create some delay before printing
    while (now < 1510592825)
    {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
        time(&now);
    }

    struct tm *timeCur;
    timeCur = localtime(&now);

    // Printing time..
    Serial.println(timeCur->tm_hour);
    Serial.println(timeCur->tm_min);
    Serial.println(timeCur->tm_sec);
}

void loop() {}
```

Comment: Well, great, I tried this code and it works. You are a true genius. Thanks a lot.

Comment: My pleasure . :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this as well for date and time

```
    #include <Arduino.h>
    #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
    #include <Time.h>
    
    void setup()
    {
      // Starting serial monitor service
      // ----------------------------------------------
      Serial.begin(9600);
    
      // Load time from the NTP server...
      time_t now;
      // Serial.println("Setting time using SNTP");
      configTime(5 * 3600, 1800, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");
      //for india UTC+5:30 so 5*3600(5 hours in seconds) and 0.5*3600=1800(half hour in seconds)
      now = time(nullptr);
    
      // create some delay before printing
      while (now < 1510592825)
      {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
        time(&now);
      }
    
    
      //experimental code //may be its not the best way, but it works well.
      struct tm* L_tm = localtime(&now);
      Serial.print("Local time: ");
      Serial.print(L_tm->tm_mday);
      Serial.print("/");
      Serial.print(L_tm->tm_mon + 1);
      Serial.print("/");
      Serial.print(L_tm->tm_year + 1900);
    
      Serial.print(" ");
    
      Serial.print(L_tm->tm_hour);
      Serial.print(":");
      Serial.print(L_tm->tm_min);
      Serial.print(":");
      Serial.println(L_tm->tm_sec);
      //experimental code END
    
    
    }
    
    void loop() {}
```